# Parse JSON array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-maps

I have a MySQL database with a table of Latitudes and longitudes with associated data. I'm trying to create a Google Map and want to parse the JSON string using JavaScript. I have looked here and on YouTube and I don't know how to solve what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my JSON string that I get with my echo statement:

```
{"cm_mapTABLE":[["1","Angels Rest Photos OR","Angels_Rest_Photos_OR","663","aaj.jpg","2","Angel's Rest","Hike one of the trails in the Gorge with a scenic overlook, stream, and waterfall.","0","blue","4.5","45.5603","-122.171","http:\/\/www.eyehike.com\/pgallery\/index.php?\/category\/6","Angels_Rest_Photos_OR\/aae.thumb.jpg\" ALIGN=left HEIGHT=115 WIDTH=150>","http:\/\/www.eyehike.com\/pgallery\/i.php?\/galleries\/Angels_Rest_Photos_OR\/aaj-th.jpg","","","",""],["2","Ape Canyon Photos WA","Ape_Canyon_Photos_WA","681","PICT0114.jpg","3","Ape Canyon Trail","This trail is popular with hikers and mountain bikers with great views of several mountains.","0","blue","11","46.1653","-122.092","http:\/\/www.eyehike.com\/pgallery\/index.php?\/category\/8","Ape_Canyon_Photos_WA\/PICT0114.thumb.jpg\" ALIGN=left HEIGHT=115 WIDTH=150>","http:\/\/www.eyehike.com\/pgallery\/i.php?\/galleries\/Ape_Canyon_Photos_WA\/PICT0114-th.jpg","","","",""]]}
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<?php
require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php"); // This is the file with your logon info

 //$host="localhost"; //replace with your hostname 
 //$username="root"; //replace with your username 
 //$password=""; //replace with your password 
 //$db_name="$database"; //replace with your database 
 $con=mysqli_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password", "$database")or die("cannot connect"); 
 //mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
 $sql = "select * from location_markers WHERE mrk_id < 3"; //replace emp_info with your table name 
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $json_string_data = array();
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $json_string_data['cm_mapTABLE'][]=$row;
    }
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 
 // You have to give the json a name to make it accessible by JS, e.g.:
//  echo 'file='.json_encode($json_string_data),';';
 
 // This statement will echo the json output in the displayed web page
 echo json_encode($json_string_data); 
 // please refer to our PHP JSON encode function tutorial for learning json_encode function in detail 
 ?>
 </head>
 <body>
    <script>
    for (i = 0;i < $json_string_data.length;i++){
    var  javascript_string_data=<?php echo json_encode($json_string_data); ?>;
        document.write(cm_mapTABLE.rank[i]);
    }
        </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm using Firebug and here is the error:

> ReferenceError: $json_string_data is not defined
>
> for (i = 0;i < $json_string_data.length;i++){

Could someone please tell me the proper way to refer to elements in my JSON string? Do I need to somehow get the field names in my JSON string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var javascript_string_data=<?php echo json_encode($json_string_data); ?>;` is forming a variable named `javascript_string_data` containing an **object**.

You are trying to access `cm_mapTABLE.rank[i]` which is actually considered as a property of the `window` object.

Try to output

```
document.write(javascript_string_data.cm_mapTABLE.rank[i]);
```

Be aware that assigning a JSON string directly could result in security issues when relying on external data previously stored into database. Use the `JSON.parse()` method instead.

Further you are trying to use a *PHP* variable in your *JavaScript* loop.

Define your JavaScript variable **before** using it in a loop:

```
var javascript_string_data = JSON.parse('<?echo json_encode($json_string_data); ?>');
for (i = 0 ; i < json_string_data.length ; i++){
    document.write(javascript_string_data.cm_mapTABLE.rank[i]);
}
```

Comment: notice: `str_replace` removed by edit since you want an object rather than a string and the code has changed to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: thanks to all, I searched the internet for format json string and found a site where I can paste my JSON output and see it formatted so I will use that for future posts. I'll use the JSON parse tonight. I got my old Google map V2 working again based on a Google spreadsheet so I have some breathing room.

Comment: In my final code I am using to fetch the mysql data. I found an example that used XML instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Note that mysql is deprecated and queries to mysql databases need to be mysqli.
For mysqli queries, you need to include the database. You can find the database name on your host's php admin page. Mine is found by logging onto phpmyadmin and choosing "Databases", then looking down the list and entering the database exactly as displayed on the list of databases. You might just have a single database.

```
<?php
// The next file has information for $hostname, $username, $password, $database
require_once("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
  $connection=new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if ($connection->connect_error)   die($connection->connect_error);

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers 
        WHERE 1
        ORDER BY rank, name";
$result = $connection-> query($query);
if (!$result)  die($connection->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j){
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
    $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("mrk_id",$row['mrk_id']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("rank", $row['rank']); 
    $newnode->setAttribute("mileage", $row['mileage']);   
    $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("marker_type", $row['type']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("mcolor", $row['mcolor']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("permalink", $row['permalink']); 
    $newnode->setAttribute("photolink", $row['photolink']); 
    $newnode->setAttribute("routelink", $row['routelink']); 
    $newnode->setAttribute("thumbnail", $row['thumbnail']); 
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

$result->close();
$connection->close();
?>

Here is the first 5 mysql records output from this code:
<markers>
<marker mrk_id="1" name="Bench Lake / Snow Lake"
rank="1" mileage="2.5" address="" lat="46.7678"
lng="-121.707" marker_type="" mcolor="blue"
permalink="https://www.eyehike.com/2016/bench-lake-snow-lake-wa/"
photolink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/344"
routelink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/345"
thumbnail="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/i.php?/galleries/Snow_Lake_Photos_WA/aai-th.jpg"
/>
<marker mrk_id="2" name="Benham Falls" rank="1"
mileage="0.4" address="" lat="43.939"
lng="-121.414" marker_type="" mcolor="blue"
permalink="https://www.eyehike.com/2016/benham-falls-or/"
photolink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/25"
routelink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/26"
thumbnail="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/i.php?/galleries/Benham_Falls_Photos_OR/aaa-th.jpg"
/>
<marker mrk_id="3" name="Big Creek Falls"
rank="1" mileage="1.6" address="" lat="46.0931"
lng="-121.908" marker_type="" mcolor="green"
permalink="https://www.eyehike.com/2016/big-creek-falls-wa/"
photolink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/27"
routelink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/28"
thumbnail="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/i.php?/galleries/Big_Creek_Falls_Photos_WA/aac-th.jpg"
/>
<marker mrk_id="4" name="Burnt Bridge Creek"
rank="1" mileage="6" address="" lat="45.6361"
lng="-122.579" marker_type="" mcolor="blue"
permalink="https://www.eyehike.com/2016/burnt-bridge-creek-trail-wa/"
photolink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/35"
routelink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/36"
thumbnail="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/i.php?/galleries/Burnt_Bridge_Creek_Photos_WA/aaq-th.jpg"
/>
<marker mrk_id="5" name="Cape Falcon Trail"
rank="1" mileage="7" address="" lat="45.7631"
lng="-123.956" marker_type="" mcolor="blue"
permalink="https://www.eyehike.com/2016/cape-falcon-or/"
photolink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/39"
routelink="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/index.php?/category/40"
thumbnail="http://www.eyehike.com/pgallery/i.php?/galleries/Cape_Falcon_Photos_OR/aae-th.jpg"
/>
</markers>
```